# How can I normalize features while preserving information about the original values?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, features, feature-engineering

I am trying to feed a neural network stock prices of an instrument. To ensure training stability, I normalize the inputs to have mean=0 and std=1.
However, I thought that for stock prices, the absolute prices of the instrument would also be relevant. This is due to the psychological effect of "round numbers", meaning we like to see clean numbers as important markers. The information of these markers is lost when normalizing.

**How can I set up the input to not lose this viable information that gets lost when normalizing?**

My initial thought was to supply the model with the important zones by providing them as extra features (e.g. the first round number above and below). But this adds extra (perhaps unneeded) complexity for the model. What are your suggestions? Am I missing an important aspect here?